Shell Extension for Windows - how to implement ContextMenu and IconOverlay in one DLL?
I'm facing a problem in Windows Shell Extensions, when combining a ContextMenu and an IconOverlay in one DLL.
Individually, both work well, but combining them in one DLL does not work.
When I register the DLL, the ContextMenu works properly. When I restart Explorer, the IconOverlay works, but once making a right-click, Explorer stops responding, like if there was an infinite loop.
Both handlers have their own GUID and their own object/unit.
I declare the types of ComObject and factory like this:
IconOverlay_U = class(TTypedComObject, IconOverlay_U, IShellIconOverlayIdentifier)
...
TIconOverlay_Factory_U = class (TTypedComObjectFactory)
...

And in the initialization I  create the objects like this:
TIconOverlay_Factory_U.Create(ComServer, TIconOverlay_U, 
          Class_IconOverlay_U, ciMultiInstance, tmBoth);

I do the same for the ContextMenu.
Can someone help? I would like to avoid providing 2 DLLs.
I tried different values for the creation of the factory, like tmApartment, but no success.
Both ComServers work well when not in the same DLL.
